# What desktop app can sync Amazon S3 with an FTP folder?

Tags: sync, ftp, cloud, cloud-storage, amazon-s3

What I'm trying to do is migrate large files off my web site to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which OS?

I think [**SuperFlexible**](http://www.superflexible.com/) (multi-platform, free trial) can, but I am not entirely sure.  If not, I cannot see why you cannot use your local storage as an intermediate point.  You'd have to be running the client software on the FTP server machine anyway, wouldn't you?

Comment: It's working in the background right now and it's a dream. Thanks! SuperFlexibile is grabbing 35GB of files from my web site and transferring them to S3.

Comment: I didn't want to use my computer as an intermediate point because I didn't want to risk losing some files or wasting time. I wanted it to happen no data risk.

Answer (score 2):

Panic's [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) app can do it on the Mac.

> You need to transfer files. Maybe to an FTP or SFTP server, or the cloud via Amazon S3, or using WebDAV. You maintain a website, do backups, or upload photos.
>
> You need Transmit, a Mac OS X FTP client.

Comment: I needed a pc program because I was on a rackspace cloud server, but I've been using Transmit lately and you're 100% right. It syncs beautifully. I only wish it worked with rackpsace cloud drives, but it's great for s3!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [CloudBerry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) hat allows to move data from SFTP/FTP to Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively try [minio client](http://minio.io/#mc) aka 'mc'. Its written in Golang, available for Windows, Mac & Linux.

mc implements the following commands

```
  ls        List files and folders.
  mb        Make a bucket or folder.
  cat       Display contents of a file.
  pipe      Write contents of stdin to one or more targets. When no target is specified, it writes to stdout.
  share     Generate URL for sharing.
  cp        Copy one or more objects to a target.
  mirror    Mirror folders recursively from a single source to many destinations.
  diff      Compute differences between two folders.
  rm        Remove file or bucket [WARNING: Use with care].
  access    Manage bucket access permissions.
  session   Manage saved sessions of cp and mirror operations.
  config    Manage configuration file.
  update    Check for a new software update.
  version   Print version.
```

mc mirror command can sync your local directory to S3 bucket.

```
$ mc mirror localDir s3/RemoteBucket
```

Hope it helps.